# Simple and quick way to get phonon dispersion?

Tags: phonons, phonon-dispersion

I want a simple phonon dispersion calculation, the lighter the program the better I do not want to install some huge package like QuantumExpresso just for that. Another way would be to find a database with phonon dispersion data for different materials, it's there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The [Materials Project](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/)

> Harnessing the power of supercomputing and state-of-the-art methods, the Materials Project provides open web-based access to computed information on known and predicted materials as well as powerful analysis tools to inspire and design novel materials.

#### The [Materials Project API](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/api#accessing-data)

> The Materials Project API allows anyone to have direct access to
> current, up-to-date information from the Materials Project database in
> a structured way.
>
> This allows for analysis, development of automated tools, machine
> learning, downloading personal copies of the Materials Project
> database and more on a large scale.
>
> The API is offered with the hopes of making Materials Project data
> more useful to you. We want you to use our data! As such, the API is
> offered free-of-charge and we support several tools to help you get
> started.

Example of phonon dispersion for $\ce{GaAs}$:
[image]

Comment: That seems great. Could you point me in the direction of a relevant tutorial?

Comment: I think that the best is to look at the project site. You will get a better info from there.

Comment: It is great. Do you know if it is possible to extract the data from the graph without all the molecular calculations formatting?

Comment: @Mauricio please post a new question for that. This question has been answered here already. Also, I'm curious why you didn't upvote the answer when you clicked "accept"?

Comment: @NikeDattani I guess the additional question is related to the answer.

Comment: @Mauricio You've asked two follow-up questions which I think both should have been in separate posts. Just because someone knows a place where you can get phonon dispersion information, doesn't mean they know where to get a **tutorial** on how to do it. Likewise, "how to extract data from a graph" or how to get data from the Materials Project API, certainly needs to be posted in a new question.

Comment: @NikeDattani I understand. I was just asking to complement the answer given which was a bit succinct. Also I wanted to know if it was possible to extract the given data not how to do it.

Comment: @Mauricio Even for related questions, unless they are really small clarifications, its generally better to have them as a separate post and link back to the previous question/answer for context. You can even alert the user you think might be able to answer by linking the new question in a comment. The benefit of a new question is that its much easier for future users to find this information than if it were it buried in the comments to a (semi-)related question/answer.

Comment: @Tyberius understood! I still think you are looking too much into it but I will do so next time.